# UIWebView Unsupported URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I'm using a UIWebView that's using an offline HTML file to manage it's workflow. 
But, every time I tap on one of the items in the UIWebView the workflow is correct but I get a console message telling me that the URL is invalid.

The message is as follows:

```
{
    NSErrorFailingURLKey = "applewebdata://BA77B31A-D9ED-4883-84BB-4270BCBEECA5?selected#node-2866424";
    NSErrorFailingURLStringKey = "applewebdata://BA77B31A-D9ED-4883-84BB-4270BCBEECA5?selected#node-2866424";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "unsupported URL";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 \"unsupported URL\" UserInfo=0x592ece0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=applewebdata://BA77B31A-D9ED-4883-84BB-4270BCBEECA5?selected#node-2866424, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=applewebdata://BA77B31A-D9ED-4883-84BB-4270BCBEECA5?selected#node-2866424, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}";
}
```

The error is quite clear, but I'm not completely sure where the error comes from, seeing that my URL is correct via the URI standard, as far as I know.

```
"applewebdata://BA77B31A-D9ED-4883-84BB-4270BCBEECA5?selected#node-2866424"
```

I don't know if there are differences between a normal HTTP URL and an AppleWebData URL, but this is correct according to the URI scheme.

e.g.:

```
scheme name:file name:query:fragment
```

Am I missing something here? I'd like to have my UIWebView do it's work without complaining about an incorrect URL, because the workflow is good. It does what I intended, but just not without being quiet.

Thanks in advance!

Bryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are loading this with `loadHTMLString:`, try setting the page's `baseUrl` as mentioned in this question: [shouldStartLoadWithRequest appending link with applewebdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358656/shouldstartloadwithrequest-appending-link-with-applewebdata)