# shouldStartLoadWithRequest appending link with applewebdata

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am receiving a description text in HTML format, and I am loading it in a webview, if a link clicked in the description so I load it in separate view controller. But shouldStartLoadWithRequest giving a some appended link. here is my code

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    WebsiteViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebsiteViewController"];
    vc.url = request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"link is : %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

it prints this

```
link is : applewebdata://038EEEBF-A4C9-4C7D-8FB5-32056714B855/www.yahoo.com
```

and I am loading it like this

```
[webViewDescription loadHTMLString:description baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you are using `loadHTMLString` and you are setting `baseURL` to nil therefore **applewebdata** URI scheme is used by iOS  instead of the “http” in URIs used for accessing internal resources on the device. You could try setting the `baseURL`

Comment: what should i put for the baseURL instead of baseURL:nil?

Comment: I ran into this problem, and in order to get the links to load correctly, I set the base URL as @"http://"

Comment: Just a small fix. The baseURL argument takes an NSURL object, so it should be `[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"]` not `@"http://"`.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue. In practice, setting the `baseURL` to 'http://' or something like that wasn't working for me either. I also only saw the `applewebdata` scheme about 50% of the time, the other 50% of the time I saw the correct scheme I was expecting.

To resolve this, I ended up intercepting `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` callbacks and using a regular expression to strip out Apple's `applewebdata` scheme. Here's what it ended up looking like

```
// Scheme used to intercept UIWebView callbacks
static NSString *bridgeScheme = @"myCoolScheme";

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    BOOL shouldStartLoad = YES;

    NSURL *requestURL = request.URL;

    // Strip out applewebdata://<UUID> prefix applied when HTML is loaded locally
    if ([requestURL.scheme isEqualToString:@"applewebdata"]) {
        NSString *requestURLString = requestURL.absoluteString;
        NSString *trimmedRequestURLString = [requestURLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"^(?:applewebdata://[0-9A-Z-]*/?)" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, requestURLString.length)];
        if (trimmedRequestURLString.length > 0) {
            requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:trimmedRequestURLString];
        }
    }

    if ([requestURL.scheme isEqualToString:bridgeScheme]) {
        // Do your thing
        shouldStartLoad = NO;
    }

    return shouldStartLoad;
}
```